# How to check a interface was registered in StructureMap?

Tags: ioc-container, structuremap

I have used StructureMap as IOC in my project and I want to check every interface that wasn't registered before in StuctureMap.

I can use `TryGetInstance` like bellow, but I think there should be a better way to do this.

```
if (continer.TryGetInstance<TPluginType>() == null)
{
  For<TPluginType>().Add<TPluggedType>();
}
```

Is there any way to check an interface or type was registered?

Comment: You could try [validating](http://structuremap.github.io/diagnostics/validating-container-configuration/) and [what do I have](http://structuremap.github.io/diagnostics/whatdoihave/)

Comment: @qujck I just need a boolean! these methods return a string and these are used for diagnostic

Comment: you could code what you want from one of these features